# NULL values after joining a CSV file to a shapefile layer on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am trying to join a CSV file to a shapefile layer (points) and after the joining all column values are NULL

I checked the joining field to be in the exact same type

Here is my data:
The shapefile

[image: The shapefile table]

The CSV file

[image]

The join fields are "Lomweight" of the shp and "Object" of the csv file

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can a schema.ini file to declare the field types: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: There's no indication of what the join field is, or what the CSV looks like before it's read, so any answer we could give would be guess and golly. Please [Edit] the Question to contain field information on both tables, the raw data, and the join rules you defined.

Comment: Thank you both, I updated the post